# Read from active tty in %post-Script during rpm-package installation

Tags: bash, tty

I've built my own rpm-packages. After installation, I need some informations from the user via keyboard input, so I've created an post-Script which is working properly if I start it from bash.

In the first step, the script is asking you if a value is correct. If you press Nn you were ask to enter the new one. Here is one example:

```
while [[ ! ($REPLY =~ ^[NnJjYy]$) ]]
do
    read -p "This is just an example, pleaser answer with NnJjYy only" -n 1 -r < $(tty)
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$ ]] 
    then 
        printf "\nValue=" 
        read HOST < $(tty)
    fi
    echo
done
```

This part is working properly if I run it directly. If I put it on the `%post`-Part of my SPEC-File, it will run as an endless loop with the errormsg "Mehrdeutige Umlenkung" which should mean "amibigious redirect" in english.

I think the problem is caused by the "$(tty)" of the read command, because if I change this to my active tty (e.g. /dev/pts/0) it's working, but I would like to have it universal.

Do you have any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: This is a bad idea to begin with. RPMs can (and often are) installed via automated processes where there is both no attached TTY and no human being to answer the question. That said, yes `tty` is likely the problem since it probably isn't returning anything usable in this context (for the above and related reasons).

Comment: RPM installation is meant to be completely non-interactive.  If you need to ask the user questions, include a setup script that can be run explicitly once the package is installed.

Comment: Thank you, i will do it that way. I`m new to the world of rpm-pkgs but familiar with debians debs. I just can remember if you install mysql-server or phpmyadmin via apt-get, there is an installwizard which will be started immediately after pkg-installation. So is this a difference of apt-get-debs and yum-rpms? (non-interactive installation)